# list index out of range(split and join)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
train_person_to_images_map = defaultdict(list)

for x in train_images:
    train_person_to_images_map([str(x).split("\\")[-3] + "\\" + str(x).split("\\")[-2]]).append(x)

    val_person_to_images_map = defaultdict(list)

    for x in val_images:
    val_person_to_images_map([ppl]).append(x)
```

for the above code, I'm getting an index error. I've posted something similar to this before also. at each and every step I'm getting this index error. can someone help me rectify this and tell me why I'm getting index error everywhere?

the error I'm getting is:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-00482029bfdd> in <module>
  2 
  3 for x in train_images:
----> 4     train_person_to_images_map([str(x).split("\\")[-3] + "\\" + str(x).split("\\") 
  [-2]]).append(x)
      5 
      6     val_person_to_images_map = defaultdict(list)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It's complaining about your data, which we have no idea about. What would `str(x)` look like? BTW, to use a `defaultdict` you must do it `like[this]`, not `like([this])`. Using parentheses would call a function, but a `defaultdict` obviously isn't callable.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the `[-3]` and `[-2]`. if `str(x).split("\\")` produces a list less than 3 items long, `str(x).split("\\")[-3]` would throw an index out of range error.